# I installed python3.12 on WSL Ubuntu, but pip is not working

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I try to run `python3.12 -m pip`, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

I have reinstalled python3.12 many times, but the error doesn't get fixed.

Comment: How did you install Python 3.12?

Comment: I have installed it using: `sudo apt-get install python3.12 `

Comment: OK, but Python 3.12 has not been released yet, so how did you get it? Where did you install it from? -- Also since it has not been released yet, issues are to be expected. -- And those issues should be reported to the maintainers or redistributors, which means not here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Distutils has been [removed](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html) in Python 3.12

Answer (score -3):

No module named 'distutils' means the package is not installed.
Have a try and install the package via apt-get.

> sudo apt-get install python3-distutils